# Lua: Compiles in native lua but error in C++ with LuaJIT and sol2

Tags: c++, lua, luajit, lua-sol

I have the following lua code, which runs fine in [an online interpreter](https://repl.it/repls/MenacingNippyComputeranimation):

```
__sprite_properties = {
    events = {}
}

function bind_event(event_name, fun)
    table.insert(__sprite_properties.events, { event_name, fun })
    print(__sprite_properties.events[1][1])
end

foo = function() 
    return 0
end
bind_event("foo_event", foo)
```

`>> foo_event`

But when I try to load and run the script in C++ using sol2 library, I've got the following error at the `table.insert` statement:

> script.lua:6: attempt to index global 'table' (a nil value)
>
> stack traceback:  script.lua:6: in function 'bind_event' --
>     script.lua:13: in main chunk

I'm using LuaJIT as lua distribution.
The code used to load the script in lua is the following snippet:

```
sol::state lua;
lua.open_libraries(sol::lib::base);
try {
    lua.safe_script_file("script.lua");
}
catch (const sol::error& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

How comes that this code can't execute properly when loaded in c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you loaded the standard Lua libraries in your C++ code? You seem to have loaded only the base library, not the table library:

```
lua.open_libraries(sol::lib::base);
```